# What XPath statement inside an XSLT file will transform the HTML below into the XML below?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xpath

I want the following table data:

```
<html>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td rowspan="2">2015</td>
<td>First Event of 2015</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Second Event of 2015</td></tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="2">2014</td>
<td>First Event of 2014</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Second Event of 2014</td></tr>
</table>
</html>
```

to get turned into the following XML using XPath:

```
<events>
<event year="2015" name="First Event of 2015">
<event year="2015" name="Second Event of 2015">
<event year="2014" name="First Event of 2014">
<event year="2014" name="Second Event of 2014">
</events>
```

How can I process the rowspans in xpath to get this output?

For the record, I'm using the following Java Code to do an XSLT Transform:

```
String xsltCode = ... // the xslt Im asking for....
File xmlInput = ... // the file with the html code above
File xmlOutput = new File("output.xml");
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xsltCode)));
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
Source xmlSource = new StreamSource(xmlInput);
Result resultOutput = new StreamResult(xmlOutput);
transformer.transform(xmlSource,resultOutput);
```

Comment: "what to the" - want to *what* the? What, exactly, is your intended result or output?

Comment: It's also not clear what exactly an "event" is. Are the `td` elements what you're calling events? The text nodes within them?

Comment: I thought it was a pretty clear question but if you need the output xml spelled out for you, there it is...

Comment: Be polite, especially if you expect others to help for free. Your initial question was definitely unclear, nobody could have guessed what you mean. But now that you have explained it: XPath is a language for _selecting_ XML content, not _manipulating_ it. You'd have to use a higher-level language like XSLT.

Comment: Sorry Mathias, but that question wasn't so bad it needed to get voted down, and now I cant post questions because it was SO bad? This is a legit question - normal people please vote this question up, thanks.

Comment: The initial downvotes were due to the question being unclear - and the others probably because people don't like your comment, implicitly saying that Charles was just too dumb to understand your question (which is not true).

Comment: The question it unclear. No environment or language specified, no information what you tried yet.

Comment: @fandang: Mathias is exceptionally good at teasing out (and answering) ambiguous questions, and [his advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28986248/how-can-i-parse-this-html-xml-with-xpath#comment46222222_28986248) is technically and socially sound.  Ignore at your own peril.

Comment: For what it's worth -- I stopped by to check in on edit status hoping to retract my downvote. The question is much less ambiguous than it was originally; the problem is, it's still not _answerable_, as the only tool it specifies is XPath, and XPath isn't powerful enough to perform the desired operation. (As for the question ban -- as long as this is your first one, it shouldn't last long).

Comment: (BTW, asking for help from "normal people", implying that high-rep users are abnormal, isn't the most politically astute thing in the world either).

Comment: ...all that said, I think this question is still salvageable: Edit it to specify more of your toolchain, such that there are tools that *can* be used for manipulation specified, and I think it'd have a good chance of getting through the reopen queue; this may simply mean adding a [[python]] tag (or similar for whatever language you're actually using), or noting that you can use XQuery or XSLT instead of raw XPath.

Comment: Sorry I dont like getting blasted with downvotes when I ask a legitimate question. I thought it was easy to understand in the first draft, but I guess not.  But thanks for looking at it again.  Maybe I don't understand the xpath terminology as well as I think I do, because to me this is a pure XPath question, not dependant on whether its java or c++ or python, but I added the java if it helps...thanks for looking again...sorry for getting touchy....

Comment: Fine, now voting to reopen.

Comment: @fandang, it's much like asking how to modify a database table using a `SELECT` query in SQL; `SELECT` isn't enough to do modifications, you need an `UPDATE` as well. XPath doesn't have an `UPDATE`; you need XQuery or XSLT (or some other programming language's database libraries) for that. Anyhow -- since you've specified XSLT, I'm in on the reopen vote now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am glad we finally worked out what you need. Please try to make your future questions clear from the outset - this will spare you time and downvotes.

Write a first template that matches `/` and outputs the outermost element of the output, `events`. Then, write a second template that matches all `td` elements that do not have a `@rowspan` attribute. The information on the year must be selected from the first preceding `td` element that *does* have a `@rowspan` attribute.

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <events>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </events>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="td[not(@rowspan)]">
        <event year="{preceding::td[@rowspan][1]}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </event>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<events>
   <event year="2015">First Event of 2015</event>
   <event year="2015">Second Event of 2015</event>
   <event year="2014">First Event of 2014</event>
   <event year="2014">Second Event of 2014</event>
</events>
```

Try this solution online [here](http://xsltransform.net/6qVRKwj).

Comment: thanks mathias, but I was hoping for an answer that could also accommodate a row that does not have a rowspan at all - could you update so that it works when the following row is added? <tr>
<td>2013</td>
<td>Only Event of 2013</td>
</tr>

Comment: @fandang Michael has already shown you a stylesheet that works with your updated input, so I will not make changes to my solution.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the given example is too simplistic, and that the actual input can also contain years with only a single event, I would suggest:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="table">
    <events>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="tr"/>
    </events>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tr">
    <event>
        <xsl:attribute name="year">
            <xsl:value-of select="(. | preceding-sibling::tr)[count(td)=2][last()]/td[1]"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="td[last()]"/>
    </event>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following **test input**:

```
<html>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">2015</td>
      <td>First Event of 2015</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Second Event of 2015</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">2014</td>
      <td>First Event of 2014</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Second Event of 2014</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Third Event of 2014</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2013</td>
      <td>Only Event of 2013</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</html>
```

the **result** will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<events>
   <event year="2015">First Event of 2015</event>
   <event year="2015">Second Event of 2015</event>
   <event year="2014">First Event of 2014</event>
   <event year="2014">Second Event of 2014</event>
   <event year="2014">Third Event of 2014</event>
   <event year="2013">Only Event of 2013</event>
</events>
```